# Generating PDF in windows forms using XML reader

Tags: c#, xml, pdf-generation, windows-forms-designer

My windows form contains a textbox in which we need to enter html tags,One button to generate PDF.
And we need to load the textbox content into XML Reader and process each element of XML recursively then we need to generate a PDF file.
The PDF file must contain the data i.e;
for example if I entered  tag in the text box in the pdf file it must display a table.
I am very new to Windows forms and XML also can any one help me to complete this task

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use a library to create PDF files. iTextSharp is a common library which can help. Take a look at this library and samples, you would be able to create PDF files easily from your application

https://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/

> iText is a PDF library that allows you to CREATE, ADAPT, INSPECT and MAINTAIN documents in the Portable Document Format (PDF):
>
> iTextSharp is the .NET port.

Answer (score 0):

Got Answer with this simple code

```
Document document = new Document();
PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream(Request.PhysicalApplicationPath + "\\MySamplePDF.pdf", FileMode.Create));
document.Open();
iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.HTMLWorker hw = 
             new iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.HTMLWorker(document);
hw.Parse(new StringReader(htmlText));
document.Close();
```

but my problem is the path I want to select the path dynamically.Can any one help me how to set the path dynamically in the above code.

Answer (score 0):

```
PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream(Request.PhysicalApplicationPath + "\\MySamplePDF.pdf", FileMode.Create));
```

Changed this code by using a savefile dialog box

```
 SaveFileDialog svg = new SaveFileDialog();
            svg.ShowDialog();

                      PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream(svg.FileName + ".pdf", FileMode.Create));
```